# Error in loading rjags: module basemod.dll not found

Tags: r

I am trying to load rjags, and I get this error message:

```
    > library(rjags)
    Loading required package: coda
    Loading required package: lattice
    Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:
      call: load.module("basemod", quiet = TRUE)
      error: File not found: C:\Program Files/x64/modules/basemod.dll
    Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rjags’
```

Apparently R cannot find `basemod.dll`. It seems that this error arised when my computer was updated to Windows 7. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Some additional info: I downloaded the latest version of JAGS and included it in my path. Furthermore, `install.packages('rjags')` does not give me any error or warning.

I'm running R version 3.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! I was reinstalling JAGS (again, but after Mike's comment I wanted to be absolutely sure), and I found the folder with the modules (incl. the file basemod.dll that R was looking for).

For reasons unclear to me, R was searching for the modules in C:\Program Files/x64/modules/..., but I had JAGS installed on D:\, so there were no modules whatsoever on C:.

I fixed it by copying the entire x64 folder of JAGS to C:\Program Files/, and that did the trick.

I admit that this solution is not very pretty, and if someone knows a better way, I am still very interested.

Answer (score 0):

Did you re-download [JAGS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/?source=dlp)?

I'm a newer user but I was getting the following error:

```
    Loading required package: coda
    Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rjags', details:
    call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
    error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/library/rjags/libs/i386/rjags.dll':
    LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

I just downloaded JAGS, loaded it and was back up.

Comment: Yes I did. I also reinstalled R, and I tried whether an older version of JAGS did work, but none of this worked unfortunately...